# IE7 not expanding div to fit ajax-loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm loading content into a series of divs using `$.load()`, and it works fine in firefox and chrome. In IE7 the page isn't redrawn after the content is loaded, so most of the content is cropped. I've read a number of related posts but none of them contains a fix for me. The js, slightly simplified:

```
$('#zoomedInLinks').load("links.cfm");
$('#zoomedInContent').load("content.cfm");
```

The pages loaded are coldfusion templates and the markup they contain has nothing odd about it (the page itself has transitional doctype). The html with placeholder divs:

```
<div id="zoomedInLinks" class="hasContent"></div>
<div id="zoomedInContent" class="hasContent"></div>
```

css, added after reading about a couple of possible fixes :

```
.hasContent {
  zoom: 1;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

I've tried altering the css before using `load`, and using `$.get()` and `innerHTML` instead, none of which helps. Any ideas? Ta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine finally found the answer to this -- jQuery was inserting a style in IE 6 and 7 that set a fixed width on one of the container divs holding the content for some reason. Overriding that fixed the problem.